# What's the official place to find latest stable version of 2.3.x Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an official webpage/blog/url to identify the latest stable version of 2.3.x Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GitHub**

See: 
https://github.com/rails/rails

and check either under Tags or Branches

Looks like 2.3.14 was the last release for 2.3.x
See: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/2-3-stable

```
gem install rails --version 2.3.14
```

You should really consider upgrading to 3.0 at least

http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2

http://railscasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `2-3-stable` tree at https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/2-3-stable is the best indicator of progress.